# How to calculate the number of page views in each session? Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to calculate the number of page views in each of the sessions on a web using Google Analytics API.

The "PageviewsperSession" indicator gets the average number of pages per session but not the number of page views per session.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of each session and for each session the number of pageviews? If so I would recommend sending a session scoped custom dimension. and then query for that dimension along with pageviews. This doesn't scale well if you have a good number of sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure you can just using the Google Analytics API but you may want to try using a custom metric and sending a 1 en every pageview.

Hope it helps!

-- EDIT:

I found the [ga:hits metric](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_hits) but im still working in excluding all hits that are not pageviews from the query...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can get at what you are looking for by using the V4 API metric expression:

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "viewId": "<YOURVIEWID>",
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "startDate": "30daysAgo",
          "endDate": "yesterday"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {
          "expression": "ga:uniquePageviews / ga:sessions",
          "alias": "Unique Page Views per Session"
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

You can play around with it with the [Request Composer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/request-composer/).